# How to set a drawable height and width?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a grid that shows drawables png files.

Now, when I press on one or more of the drawables it shows it in a EditText field.

The thing is that the image is a bit too large compared to the text, so what I would like to know is how can I adjust the size of the drawables?

I guess that it got to do with the next code -

```
    @Override
public Drawable getDrawable(String arg0) {


    int id = 0;

    if(arg0.equals("zero.png")){
        id = R.drawable.emoji_0030;
    }

    if(arg0.equals("slash.png")){
        id = R.drawable.emoji_0023;
    }
    LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
    Drawable empty = getResources().getDrawable(id);
    d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), empty.getIntrinsicHeight());

    return d;

}
```

So I tired to change the - d.setBounds - to let's say -

```
d.setBounds(0, 0, 10, 10);
```

Or even to the next code (just to see if it makes a difference) -

```
d.setBounds(5, 5, 5, 5);
```

But nothing is happening.

So if somone tell me where should I place the figures for the height and width, it will be nice.

Or maybe there's another way to do what I'm trying to do over here?

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: what are you doing with returned LevelListDrawable drawable ?

Comment: Well I assumed it had to do something with this function - but seem like I was wrong

Comment: do you use DynamicDrawableSpan ?

Comment: where do you keep R.drawable.emoji_* files?

Comment: at a drawable folder - NOT in any other drawable folders like drawable-hdpi - and etc

Comment: thats why it upscaled, try for testing purposes move it to drawable-nodpi

Comment: Well done  pskink - you are the brilliant one over here, turns out I'm bit stupid - Thanks